# Sublime text editor cannot find the file specified to run Java code

Tags: java, sublimetext2

Sublime text editor cannot find the file specified to run Java code.
I tried a series of steps I found online advising me to set path to bin, and so on so forth. Finally, I come across this error message about Sublime not finding the file specified to run the code...
The image below displays the error code. Thanks in advance.

[Displays error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJUfk.png)/z8PVQ.png

Answer (score 0):

Before running the program, open up a command prompt and try these commands to see if Java is installed correct. `java -version` and `javac`. These confirm you have configured the environment variables correctly.